# JAXB gives me: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is parameter must not be null

Tags: java, jaxb

I am doing this using JAXB to unmarshall some XML into Java objects:

My code looks a little like this:

```
InputStream testMsg = getClass().getResourceAsStream("TestDocumentEvent.xml");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(DocumentEvent.class).createUnmarshaller();
DocumentEvent unmarshalled = (DocumentEvent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(testMsg);
```

However, when I run this code I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is parameter must not be null
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because the `InputStream` you are passing to the unmarshaller ('is' parameter, geddit) is null, check that the resource name is correct.

Comment: I know, I answered my own question. I added this because there isn't much on google about this and the error isn't that readable

Comment: I don't know, it seems pretty obvious to me - if the unmarshal call is complaining immediately that its argument is null, what's unreadable about that?

Comment: You are saying that "IS" is short for "InputStream" in the complaint? Yes, that's a little unclear, but at least from context it's easy to figure out.

Comment: @Jon, if the world was made of Jon Skeets we wouldn't need SO, if your rep is anything to go by. Sadly marginal code jockeys such as myself still need a helping hand once and awhile.

Comment: Thanks - obvious enough one, but never made the connection - "is parameter must not be null" always sounded like a grammar error to me.

Comment: Yeah I don't get why they thought it was beneficial to abbreviate, especially since the overloaded call that takes in a SteamSource (param name = source) will give that same error... is = source ? Ugh. Anyways, they should have written: is par must ! b \0. What's not to understand!

Comment: @SCdF So, you wrote the absolute path to the correct .xml file?